# Entity Framwork Model First - After update login faild

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, mdf

I wrote a small application with entity Framework 6 model first Approach and SQL Server Express 2012

It worked well the last 6 month. Today, I deployed an update of the application with new Features, but no changes on the data layer. After deinstalled the old Version and installed the new Version I am not able to connect to the database. The messages "Login failed for user ...", but I never set an user somewhere. Also in the Management Studio I am not able to include the MDF file again... also a Login issue... I use default Windows authentication.

I need the data from the mdf file! Any ideas how to get it running again?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: The code for the connection is fully autogenerated... Ans i made no changes... I reinstalled the previous Version, which was running with this file ans the same login issue appears.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after trying a lot things I found in the web... I tried a MDF repair tool [Link](http://www.stellarinfo.com/sql-recovery.htm). It is just a demo Version so I was not able to create a new MDF file, but I have Access to the data. So now, I look arround for free Recovery Tools. I will post here if I found one... In the meanwhile, if someone has some recommendations please tell me!